# Why does Rails CSS for all links not work, but works with :class => "foo"?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very strange problem. I have got a Rails page in which I want to use CSS to format all links, and there are menu links which should have another color. So I started out with

```
    .menulink:link, .menulink:visited, .menulink:hover, .menulink:active{
        color: red;
    }
```

in the menubar fragment CSS (`sidebar.css.scss`)

For all other links, I wrote CSS into `application.css.scss`:

```
    a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
        color: green;
    }
```

Interestingly, this does not work. BUT if I add a class tag to any link in my code, like so

```
    <%= link_to "Alle Artikel", :controller => :articles, :action => :index, :class => "foo" %>
```

it works perfectly. I really am confused. Why this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a class foo css in your code that may affect the layout.

Comment: I don't get your question clearly but you have to add a class in a link like this `<%= link_to "Alle Artikel", {:controller => :articles, :action => :index}, :class => "foo" %>`

Comment: That's why using `:controller` + `:action` isn't recommended. Use: `articles_path` instead and you won't be confused about the place of `:class` option.

Comment: What sort of browser tools are you using?  A good development setup (I like Firefox with the Firebug extension) will let you see which CSS rules apply to each element (and which ones got overridden).

Comment: Actually no, I don't have any other css rules than the mentioned one. Especially none, which makes anchors grey (but that's what they become...)

I've tried articles_path as well, but it didn't change the outcome in any form. Links still grey. 

Ah, actually I use firefox and firebug, that's a very good suggestion, xavier. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be seeing the 'cascading' in Cascading Style Sheets.
Basically it seems that when you place a specific class selector the class gets applied.  That's the rule with css, the more specific the rule the more it will apply any higher level 'global' settings.
So when you apply the rule at a higher general level such as all anchors, what may be happening is that there are style rules at lower levels than "all anchors" but at a higher level than the class/tag and this may help explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Actually I thought about that as well. But actually I have nowhere defined a css style that makes my anchors grey (but the become that color). Are there by any chance default css styles that rails defaults to?

Comment: Turns out there was a scaffolding.css.scss which contained a 

a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }

So it was indeed cascading as in cascading style sheets...

Comment: no problem.  Browser tools such as firebig and Chrome developer tools can help a lot with this.

Answer (score 1):

Reformat like this:

```
<%= link_to "Alle Artikel", {:controller => :articles, :action => :index}, :class => "foo" %>
```

Comment: Ah that's interesting! If I do this, then it also doesn't work, even if I add :class => "foo" with any css class name.
so 
        <%= link_to "Alle Artikel", {:controller => :articles, :action => :index, :class => "foo"} %>
works, but
        <%= link_to "Alle Artikel", {:controller => :articles, :action => :index}, :class => "foo" %>

Comment: That doesn't make sense, having the :class declaration inside of the curly braces will send class as a parameter. Ex. `<a href="/articles?class=foo">Alle Artikel</a>` Where as having it outside of the curly braces will give the anchor a class. Ex. `<a href="/articles" class="foo"></a>`